# Transient analysis with Laplace and nodal analysis error

Tags: circuit-analysis, transient, laplace-transform

Have the schematic:

[image]

Solving using MathCAD:

[image]

There is an error in my equations with nodal analysis but I can't find where? May anyone help me?

I also add the solution using approach of series RLC circuit:

[image]

But it seems to be A1 and A2 constant sign is incorrect comparing my result with that in textbook.

I also tried to solve with Laplace but using Mesh Current Method, my equations are (I1 - left mesh current, I2 - right):

[image]

But same thing - I can't get properly result, may be something wrong but I can't understand what!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thevenin Equiv circuit for v1 goes from 60V to 40% or 24V with Rs=30//20=12 ohms.  The steady state v(t) across cap is then +24-30= -6Vdc

Then we know resonance ω= √(L/C)= v(0.5) = 0.707 and Q=XL/R = 2 π 0.5/12 which is <1 and thus overdamped and the initial voltage across cap will be 0V.

Does this method make it easier than Laplace?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be easy but applies to current circuit. I need more general solution that applies to any 2-order circuit but your tips are good!

Comment: I add my solution using your approach and I get an answer. Only difference with textbook answer that the signs of A1 and A2 are inversed in textbook answer. Why it so?

Answer (score 1):

The node equations are correct, and the expression for \$v_2\$ is also correct. Check your analysis for \$v_1\$.

Comment: I add the inverse Laplace Transform from MathCAD to post text and the result voltage I think must be the difference of equations for v1 - v2. But there is a strange result. It must be in an exponentional form but not what I get. There is a trick somewhere?

Comment: By inspection of the circuit, the final value of v(t) is: 24 - 30 = -6 V, which is the same as your final equation gives.

Comment: But I must find the equation of v(t) not simply final value. The problem is I use same steps in other tasks and the inverse Laplace of node voltage give me the right result but not here, I can't understand why? May the MathCAD not work properly with my equation or not I don't know.

Comment: I know you want v(t), my point is that your equations are giving -6V at infinity, which you say is the correct answer.

Comment: Is there any suggestion why I get an incorrect inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: As I said at the onset, the expression for v1(s) is completely wrong in the column vector.

Comment: Is it possible that MathCAD symbol processor gives incorrect result?

Comment: It seems to be an error in my nodal equations. For Laplace if I wrote the equations I can simply take inverse transform and get the right result but here there is not working, but must!

Comment: Your initial node equations are correct. As I said, check the analysis. You can derive v1 from v2 and one of node equations. Your v2 eqn is correct

Comment: I'm trying to check v1, v2 equations on paper and now I get very long equations that in current moment I can't write all in usable view. I think there is a trick here because some tasks are solved too easy with Laplace.

Comment: I add to post the mesh currents method equation but solving that don't give me correct result. I found I2(s) and multiply that by Laplace capacitor impedance.

Answer (score 0):

> There is an error in my equations with nodal analysis but I can't find
> where?

Your nodal equations *are correct* (assuming zero initial conditions). The expressions for \$V_1(s)\$ and \$V_2(s)\$ (in the frequency domain) are also correct. Regarding the expressions for \$v_1(t)\$ and \$v_2(t)\$ (in the time domain), I'm not sure if yours (using hyperbolic functions) are correct, but using exponential functions below I show them along with a plot.

[image: Plot]

The following simulation checks the previous result:

[image: Simulation]